# Should I uninstall snap after removing vtop?

Tags: snap

I am totally new in Linux world and I installed snap from a tutorial and tried to install VTOP to know what is it. The app works, but I got this warning message:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:339:9)
    at sudo (/snap/vtop/1/lib/node_modules/vtop/node_modules/sudo/lib/sudo.js:30:17)
    at Object.upgrade.install (/snap/vtop/1/lib/node_modules/vtop/upgrade.js:58:16)
    at Screen.<anonymous> (/snap/vtop/1/lib/node_modules/vtop/app.js:489:14)
    at Screen.EventEmitter._emit (/snap/vtop/1/lib/node_modules/vtop/node_modules/blessed/lib/events.js:86:20)
    at Screen.EventEmitter.emit (/snap/vtop/1/lib/node_modules/vtop/node_modules/blessed/lib/events.js:103:17)
    at Program.<anonymous> (/snap/vtop/1/lib/node_modules/vtop/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:568:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
```

Should I uninstall snap after removing VTOP?

Comment: No need to uninstall snap after removing vtop. If you do sudo snap remove vtop It will remove the package and you do not need to worry. Snap packages are sandboxed and do not interfere with your system and the installed libraries. They will stay out of your way and would be easily managed independent of the Operating System. In short you do not need to uninstall snap.

Comment: @RajatPandita, Could you write that as answer. seem to me a good one

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall snap after removing vtop. If you do sudo snap remove vtop It will remove the package and you do not need to worry. Snap packages are sandboxed and do not interfere with your system and the installed libraries. They will stay out of your way and would be easily managed independent of the Operating System. In short you do not need to uninstall snap